# Something is not right with this PHP/JavaScript multi-file upload form

Tags: javascript, php

Hi fellow Stack Overflowers!

I am developing a feature that lets me automatically upload files using XMLHTTP requests, supporting drag-and-drop, and even multiple files. The problem is, it doesn't seem like the server is receiving the file. So, either I'm referencing the wrong variable, or my JavaScript code isn't actually transmitting the file.

For a little background: I used this code on a commercial project almost two years ago, and sourced it somewhere else for continued development. That source has since disseminated, and this is the latest version I can find. I haven't used JavaScript much over the last year, so a fresh set of eyes or two might get me going in the correct direction.

Thanks in advance for the help!

-Tim

```
<?php
echo 'hi';
if(isset($_SESSION['adminId'])){

    if(!isset($_GET['use'])){
        echo 'Use must be specified to load upload form!';
    }elseif($_GET['use'] == 'product'){
        //load images, and then assign each one to the product via database...
        if(!isset($_GET['productId'])){
            die("We need a product ID!");
        }else{
            if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

                $arout = [];
                //upload images to products directory, and then assign the image id.
                $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "bmp");
                $max_file_size = 1024*1000000; //1,000,000 kb
                $path = "../resources/images/uploads/product/"; // Upload directory
                $count = 0;
                $filez = $_FILES['files'];
                header("Diag: True, ".count($filez));
                foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     

                    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                        continue; // Skip file if any error found
                    }          
                    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
                        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                            continue; // Skip large files
                        }
                        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
                        }
                        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 

                            $info = new SplFileInfo($name);
                            $ext = $info->getExtension();

                            //generate db
                            $daba->real_query("INSERT INTO `media` (`extension`, `owner`) VALUES ('".$ext."', '".$_SESSION[adminId]."');");

                            $imageid = $daba->insert_id;

                            $name = $imageid.'.'.$ext;

                            $filepath = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f];

                            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)){

                            }

                            $count++;
                        }
                    }
                    header("Responses: ".$message);
                }
        }else{
            echo <<<EOT
<html>
<body id="drop-body">
<center><h3 style="margin: 0;">Upload Images</h3></center>
<input id="files-upload" style="display: none;" name="files" type="file" accept='image/*' multiple>
    <p id="drop-area">
    <label for="files-upload">
    <span class="drop-instructions"><a>Browse files</a></span>
    </label>
    <span id="noShow" class="drop-hereherehere">or drag and drop files here</span>
    <span class="drop-over">Drop files here!</span>
    </p>

    <ul id="file-list">
    <li class="no-items" style="display: none;"></li>
    </ul>

    <style>
    body{
        background: #000;
        color: #fff
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #drop-area{
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #file-list{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #file-list li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 4px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    }
    #file-list li img{
        max-height: 100px;
    }
    .drop-instructions{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 4px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
        height: 124px;
        width: 124px;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .drop-instructions a{
        display: block;
        margin: 40px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .drop-over{
        position: absolute;
top: 50vh;
left: calc(50vw - 50px);
z-index: 0;
display: block;
color: gray;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
    var filesUpload = document.getElementById("files-upload"),
    dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-body"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("file-list");

    document.getElementById("noShow").style.display = "none";

    function uploadFile (file) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"),
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    img,
    progressBarContainer = document.createElement("div"),
    progressBar = document.createElement("div"),
    reader,
    xhr,
    fileInfo;

    li.appendChild(div);

    progressBarContainer.className = "progress-bar-container";
    progressBar.className = "progress-bar";
    progressBarContainer.appendChild(progressBar);
    li.appendChild(progressBarContainer);

    /*
    If the file is an image and the web browser supports FileReader,
    present a preview in the file list

    */
    if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined" && (/image/i).test(file.type)) {
    img = document.createElement("img");
    li.appendChild(img);
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (theImg) {
    return function (evt) {
    theImg.src = evt.target.result;
    };
    }(img));
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    // Uploading - for Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Update progress bar
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    progressBar.style.width = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100 + "%";
    }
    else {
    // No data to calculate on
    }
    }, false);

    // File uploaded
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
    progressBarContainer.className += " uploaded";
    progressBar.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
    }, false);

    xhr.open("POST", "/admin/upload?use=product&productId=$_GET[productId]", true);


    // Set appropriate headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

    // Send the file (doh)
    xhr.send(file);

    // Present file info and append it to the list of files

    fileList.appendChild(li);
    }

    function traverseFiles (files) {
    if (typeof files !== "undefined") {
    for (var i=0, l=files.length; i<l; i++) {
    uploadFile(files[i]);
    }
    }
    else {
    fileList.innerHTML = "No support for the File API in this web browser";

    }
    }

    filesUpload.addEventListener("change", function () {
    traverseFiles(this.files);
    }, false);

    dropArea.addEventListener("dragleave", function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;

    if (target && target === dropArea) {
    this.className = "";
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    }, false);

    dropArea.addEventListener("dragenter", function (evt) {
    this.className = "over";
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    }, false);

    dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    }, false);

    dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function (evt) {
    traverseFiles(evt.dataTransfer.files);
    this.className = "";
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    }, false);
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
        }
    }}
}else{
    die("Unauthorized access!");
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post you're JavaScript too, otherwise we have no idea what input data the PHP is getting.

Comment: a) There are various modern/uptodate JS libs that allow AJAX file uploads with drag and drop and multi file support. Even for Vanilla JS.

Comment: The JavaScript is a part of the main HTML code, listed after "echo <<<EOT" in the code I posted. The JavaScript is towards the bottom.

Comment: b) Use the browser development tools. Make use of it, check the networks tab and inspect the request.

Comment: c) You can simply dump `$_FILES` and see if a file got received. `var_dump` is the preferred function for debugging (next to a real debugger).

Comment: I should have mentioned that, I did check the network activity using the browser development tools, and it did appear that the file was sent. However, when I tried var_dump() on the files, it didn't return anything. I ended up using the count() function on the $_FILES array, which returned 0. When I inspected the request, it shows varying sizes. But it almost appears that the files are sent on different requests as the original XMLHTTP POST request.

Comment: The last time I made this code work, I vaguely recall it was something very simple in the JavaScript section. I almost thought the problem was around "xhr.send(file)".